# Files directory in an Ansible role

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I probably need a second pair of eyes on this. I have a role, where one of the tasks, I am simply copying files from the *files/* directory to the remote destination. While this is super simple, when I run the playbook, it cannot find the files on the control node. I am running this from AWX against a git repository.

```yaml
- name: Copy certificate and key files to the destination
  copy:
    src: "files/{{ item.netbios | lower }}.{{ item.file_type }}"
    dest: "{{ nginx_ssl_dest }}/{{ item.netbios | lower }}.{{ item.cert_ext }}.{{ item.file_type }}"
  when: answer == 'True' and app_netbios == item.netbios
  register: cert_copy
  loop: "{{ files_to_copy }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "Copying {{ item.netbios }}.{{ item.file_type }}"
  vars:
    files_to_copy:
      - { netbios: 'domain', cert_ext: 'ini', file_type: 'crt' }
      - { netbios: 'domain', cert_ext: 'ini', file_type: 'key' }
      - { netbios: 'domain2', cert_ext: 'ini', file_type: 'crt' }
      - { netbios: 'domain2', cert_ext: 'ini', file_type: 'key' }
```

Here is the error I am getting back:

```
failed: [testserver] (item=Copying domain.crt) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": {"cert_ext": "ini", "file_type": "crt", "netbios": "domain"}, "msg": "Could not find or access '/tmp/bwrap_k2q_hi_g/awx_/project/files/domain.ini.crt' on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"}

An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: If you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src

failed: [testserver] (item=Copying domain.key) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": {"cert_ext": "ini", "file_type": "key", "netbios": "domain"}, "msg": "Could not find or access '/tmp/bwrap_k2q_hi_g/awx_/project/files/domain.ini.key' on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"}
```

I've done this plenty of times with other roles, but today, I seem to be missing something. I believe it's something simple. If you have any idea I am open.

I believe the best to handle this is to use a `when` condition when the other domain is present and loop through my variables. This will be my other option. This was an attempt to condense 4 tasks into one task.

I have verified the *files/* directory does contain the files and names to match when searching for the file to copy.

Comment: Regarding the statement "_I have verified the files/ directory does contain the files and names to match_" and the error message `"Could not find or access '/tmp/bwrap_k2q_hi_g/awx_/project/files/...`, isn't that, the name not changing everytime? As far as I understand the path contains a random part: `/tmp/<random>/awx_/...`.

Comment: I will check an existing ansible role, that uses the files/ in the role. I would normally see a path like that listed in the output when executing a playbook. I believe that’s expected. I’ll verify in about 4-5hours from now.

Comment: Right, the source `src: "files/{{ YOURFILE | lower }}.{{ FILETYPE }}"` is within the role usually. There could also be the reason. Since you are using `| lower`, maybe the files are case-sensitve, or have missing rights too, or just other names, etc. ...

Comment: There are many details missing in your question to make sure you crossed all check boxes regarding using [the magic of local paths](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbook_pathing.html#resolving-local-relative-paths), Are you sure you are using the above task directly from your role and that your role is correctly included (e.g. not through `include_tasks`...)?

Comment: Setting the AWX verbosity in the job template (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html#job-templates) will actually cause the `ansible-playbook` command to run like prompted (with `-vvv`). In verbose mode, trying to access a file or template will also lists you the path where ansible looked for the file when failing.

Comment: @Zeitounator - I see what the issue is. I am excuting the include_task within my role, however, I noticed when I include those playbooks, vars_files or anything included within that included playbook, it searches outside of the role. Apologies for the vague information. I am excuting my role in this design: main.yml -> includes a task to deploy nginx, within that task I was having issues reaching files/ directory, within the role. Then I included another task, which also searches outside of the role. Which is odd.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I added more verbosity - here is an example: task path: /tmp/bwrap_2222/awx_2228/project/roles/deploy_nginx/tasks/main.yml, which includes /tmp/bwrap_2222/awx_2228/project/roles/deploy_nginx/tasks/deploy-ngnix.yml <--- tasks executed within this playbook looks for files/ or additional included tasks outside of the role. I ran into this before, but I did not document the issue.